# Nested Attributes for a Model Through Multiple Belongs To

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have three models.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :employee

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :slave

  belongs_to :business

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :slave
end

class Slave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

I have some slave params being sent to my controller to update the slave and business record. The slave params consist of a key `business_attributes` with updated business attributes. However I'm unsure of how to properly hook it up.

Should I add an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the slave model to accept `business_attributes`? Or do I need to have `business_attributes` wrapped up inside an `employee_attributes` hash and have the employee model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for `business_attributes`? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd say you might be overcomplicating your structure, or forms if you need to pass data in this way. You could instead use your business controller to process the form logic using the relationships you already have.

If you do absolutely need to pass business attributes directly into the slave, you'd need to create some sort of relationship directly between the slave and business. Something like:

```
delegate :business, to: :employee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :business
```

*Note: This is untested, and could serve to be inefficient if you're frequently referencing the business from the slave (n+1 queries).